# How to toggle visibility of 2 divs after clicking a mailto link?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following `mailto` link

```
<div class="send_email">
 <a href="mailto:name@email.com">Send email</a>
</div>
```

After it is clicked I want to hide the 'send email' div and show the 'email sent' div

```
<div class="email_sent">
 <p>Email sent</p>
 <a href="http://www.example.com/clear_sent">I changed my mind and didn't send the email</a>
</div>
```

Then after I click the I 'changed my mind' link it must then show the 'send email' div

CSS will be something like

```
.email_sent {
 visibility: hidden;
}
```

I have jquery installed but am not sure how to show and hide and then show the above divs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(function(){
  $('.send_email > a').click(function(){
    $('.send_email').hide();
    $('.email_sent').show();
  });
});
```

```css
.email_sent { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="send_email">
 <a href="mailto:name@email.com">Send email</a>
</div>
<div class="email_sent">
 <p>Email sent</p>
 <a href="http://www.example.com/clear_sent">I changed my mind and didn't send the email</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.send_email a').on('click', function() {
        $(this).parent().hide();
        $('.email_sent').show();
    });
});
```

With the following CSS:

```
.email_sent {
    display: none;
}
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/eo793y7m/2/) is a working example.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".send_email a").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    
    
    $(".email_sent").removeClass("hidden");
    $(".send_email").addClass("hidden");    
    
    //Open send mail
    var email = 'test@yourdomain.com';
    var subject = 'your subject';
    var emailBody = 'Some blah';
    window.location = 'mailto:' + email + '?subject=' + subject + '&body=' +   emailBody;

  })
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="send_email">
 <a href="#">Send email</a>
</div>

<div class="email_sent hidden">
 <p>Email sent</p>
 <a href="http://www.example.com/clear_sent">I changed my mind and didn't send the email</a>
</div>
```